# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() using laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i have multiple images in an annonces table field, i want to display these images in show.blade.php but it gives me error `Invalid argument supplied for foreach ()`.

**show.blade.php**

```
@if ($annonces->images)
 @foreach (json_decode($annonces->images, true) as $images)
    <div class="item" data-slide-number="16">
        <img src="{{ Voyager::image($images) }}" style="width:600px;height:400px">
                                        </div>
 @endforeach
@endif
```

**AnnoncesController.php**

```
public function show($id)
    {
        $annonces = Annonce::where('id',$id)->firstOrfail();
         return view('annonces.details', ['annonces' => $annonces]);
    }
```

Comment: I feel like you have asked this 3 times now   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64032877/how-to-display-images-of-a-product-using-laravel-voyager https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64031168/invalid-argument-supplied-for-foreach-using-laravel-6

Comment: The issue is with `images`. Try `dd($annonces->images);` in your controller before you return the view to see what it contains

Comment: @aynber thx for answer dd($annonces->images) give me error Property [images] does not exist on this collection instance.

Comment: your controller is returning a view named `annonces.details` ... you are showing us a view called `show` ... does annonces.details include show ?  the error you are showing does not match up with what is in the view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$annonces->images must be valid json format you might using comma separated string
```

you can try following

```
@if ($annonces->images)
 @foreach (explode(',', $annonces->images) as $images)
    <div class="item" data-slide-number="16">
        <img src="{{ Voyager::image($images) }}" style="width:600px;height:400px">
                                    </div>
 @endforeach
@endif
```

Thanks